# hide balance images in animate

Tags: jquery, css

The animate code jquery is working fine but entire images are appearing.  I want only the one image to be appeared in sequence manner. I have tried for the looping but not working. Could any body correct the code?

```
<div class="banner" id="first-banner"> <img src="http://www.xyz.jpg"> </div>
<div class="banner" id="first-banner"> <img src="http://www.xyz2.jpg"> </div>
<div class="banner" id="first-banner"> <img src="http://www.xyz3.jpg"> </div>
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/track/3eZk4/2/)

Comment: Please try to clarify your question for it is very unclear.

Comment: You have a few typos in your CSS that might be getting in the way.  Here is a fixed fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3eZk4/5/ (the dot before the img selector was looking for elements with the class 'img' not `<img>` elements.  also position was misspelled.

Comment: please clarify your question.

Comment: with single image, the code in [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/track/3eZk4/2/) works fine. When it comes to many images in sequal manner, it wont works?

Answer (score 0):

Please update your CSS:

EXISTING CSS (with errors) :-

```
.img {
    width: 400px;
    height: 150px;
    postion: absolute
}
```

**NEW CSS**

```
img {
    width: 400px;
    height: 150px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Hope this helps!